# to avoid page refresh during button click event in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)  // If page loads for first time
    {
        Session["update"] = Server.UrlEncode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());   // Assign the Session["update"] with unique value

        //=============== Page load code =========================





        //============== End of Page load code ===================
    }

}



protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["update"].ToString() == ViewState["update"].ToString())    // If page not Refreshed
    {
        //=============== On click event code =========================

        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
        //lblDisplayAddedName.Text = txtName.Text;


        //=============== End of On click event code ==================

        // After the event/ method, again update the session  
        Session["update"] = Server.UrlEncode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
    }
    else  // If Page Refreshed
    {
        // Do nothing 
    }
}
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["update"] = Session["update"];
}

}
```

This is not working for high resolution gradient background.

Answer (score 2):

Consider wrapping your button and the label in an `updatepanel` control, which uses AJAX to refresh their contents. 
The rest of the page will not be reloaded and the action will not affect the browser navigation.

See [this page](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Documentation/Live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx) on how an `updatepanel` control works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are handling the button click event in server side there has to be a postback to handle it.

If you do not want a post back to happen change the event handling to "client click"

Answer (score 0):

//Heinzi code worked for me just made a small change in OnPreRender event, assign the ViewsState value when its not post back

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["update"] = Session["update"];

        }

    }
```